# Multiple Valid PDAs with the same seeds but Different Bump?

Tags: pda, bump

Is it possible to have multiple valid [PDAs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#hash-based-generated-program-addresses) (off the curve) using the same `seeds`? since `bump` can be from 0 to 255.

---

**find_program_address**

> This function will do its very best to find an address off the curve.
> It will take the seeds you give it and also concatenate a nonce (the
> bump) to it, and the bytestring "ProgramDerivedAddress", counting down
> from 255 to 0 ([ref](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/298/findprogramaddress-is-not-returning-the-original-address-created-even-though-i))

it's also seen [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#hash-based-generated-program-addresses)

```
pub fn find_program_address(seeds: &[&[u8]],program_id: &Pubkey) -> Option<(Pubkey, u8)> {
    let mut bump_seed = [std::u8::MAX];
    for _ in 0..std::u8::MAX {
        ..
        ..
        bump_seed[0] -= 1;
    }
    None
}
```

**find_program_address** will stop when it finds a valid PDA and will return both the `address` and the `bump`. if I skip the first valid PDA. is it possible to find another one that's also valid (different `bump`)?

If yes then would it cause a security hazard if you use the second `bump` for a PDA in a program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"if I skip the first valid PDA. is it possible to find another one that's also valid"

Yes, there are multiple PDAs to be found, in fact up to 255.
However, all programs should verify the PDA provided is using the canonical PDA, as in the first valid PDA decrementing the bump_seed starting from `std::u8::MAX`.

With anchor it is as simple as using the `bump` constraint.